# 2-Handler сommands не выполняется

Tags: python, telegram

Есть 2 хендлера c параметром commands:
Когда я вызываю команду "sklad" и "tovar" все равно выполняется 1-хендлер.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где моя ошибка.
Спасибо.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['sklad'])
def message_handler_send(message: types.Message):
    if message.text in koppon:   
        send_docs(message)
    elif message.text in yuksak:
        send_docs_yuksak(message)
    elif message.text in yaypan:
        send_docs_yaypan(message)
    elif message.text in yangiqurgon:
        send_docs_yangiqurgon(message)
    elif message.text=='d':
        send_docs_oboy(message)
    else:
        send_query(message)

 @bot.message_handler(commands=['tovar'])
 def message_handler_query(message: types.Message):
 message.text=message.text[1:]
 if message.text not in (koppon, yuksak, yaypan, yangiqurgon) and (message.text.startswith('s')):
    send_query_yuksak(message)
 elif message.text not in (koppon, yuksak, yaypan, yangiqurgon) and (message.text.startswith('y')):
    send_query_yaypan(message)
 elif message.text not in (koppon, yuksak, yaypan, yangiqurgon) and (message.text.startswith('g')):
    send_query_yangiqurgon(message)
 elif message.text not in (koppon, yuksak, yaypan, yangiqurgon) and (message.text.startswith('d')):
    send_query_oboy(message)
```

Comment: А у Вас на чём бот написан? Может быть полезно - https://stepik.org/lesson/666085/step/2

Comment: Что такое koppon, yuksak? Что там?  Смущает if message.text not in (koppon, yuksak,.... Как Вы вызываете /tovar text ? Ещё может message.text=message.text.strip()

Comment: прочитал тут , stepik.org/lesson/666085/step/2 все ошибки исправил, сспасибо вам.